# Batch converting JPEG and MP4 to HEIF

Tags: heic

is there a way to batch/bulk convert JPEG and MP4 files to HEIF/HEIC? There are a lot of tools to convert in the other direction one by one.

Since people asking: online converters are not suitable since the library has 300 GB of JPEG and 200 GB of MP4.
They are not able to bulk process such an amount of data.

I want to convert all files on a Windows system.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to convert mp4 *video* files into image formats?

Comment: Why would you want to do so? You won't gain the extra bit depth because the additional information has already been discarded when the JPEG or MP4 was made.

Comment: @xiota HEIC can be either still images or animation/video.

Comment: Heic creates smaller files than JPEG, which is helpful when storing those images in icloud. Please don't ask why and whatever. I was asking for the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "please don't ask why and whatever". See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Once you've been on the stackexchange network for a while you'll notice that the problem someone wants to solve has a different solution then they had in mind at first. That's why people ask *why* you want to do something, because maybe there's an easier way to reach the same goal.

Comment: Also, could you please include the research you've done so far? When I look up "JPEG to HEIF converter" I find plenty of (online) converters. Could you indicate, by editing your question, why those are not helpful?

Comment: The online converters are not able to bulk convert. My library has 15000 photos.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is capable of exporting in HEIF format (see [section 1.2.2 in docs](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-images-out.html#save-export-image)).

It also looks like [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com) is possibly capable of it (I can't vouch for this as I am on a mac, and don't want to spin up a VM just to test). Irfanview also seems to have batch processing, which I can't seem to find in GIMP.

Comment: 1. OP wants to convert MP4 video files, which GIMP does not support. 2. Irfanview is capable of opening HEIF files (with proper codecs installed), but cannot export them.

Comment: Thank you bob1.  GIMP is able to bulk convert photos. This helps.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of ImageMagick [support HEIC](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) so batch conversion could be as simple as

```
for f in *.JPG;
do
   magick convert "$f" ${f%%.*}.heic
done
```

Comment: 1. The page you link indicates ImageMagick has *only* read support. When attempting to write heic files, it gives the following error: `magick.exe: Unsupported file-type: Unspecified \`test.heic' @ error/heic.c/IsHeifSuccess/134.` 2. ImageMagick often silently generates jpgs, so the image format needs to be confirmed. 3. Even if this worked, it doesn't address converting mp4 video files. 4. The scripting language you're using appears to be `bash`, which does not *normally* work with Windows.

Comment: **This answer is incorrect because ImageMagick does not have the ability to *write* heif files.**